# How to embed Google finance historical charts on a website?

Tags: php, ajax, currency, google-visualization, financial

It's easy enough to link to these [financial charts at Google finance](http://www.google.com//finance?chdnp=1&chdd=1&chds=1&chdv=1&chvs=Linear&chdeh=0&chfdeh=0&chdet=1315699479508&chddm=27620&q=CURRENCY:EURUSD&ntsp=0), but how to embed them on a website? Is there a way to do it that doesn't involve too much programming? I want to embed these charts for a project I'm working on at [cashexchangerates.com](http://www.cashexchangerates.com). If it's not possible, any suggestions for alternative chart sources would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you need the chart to be interactive as well?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need the chart to be interactive. You could get the alt image from Google. For example the URL

http://www.google.com/finance/getchart?q=EURUSD&x=CURRENCY&p=1Y&i=86400

Will show the following image:

[image: 1 Year Chart of the index]

Looks like that :

- p is the period where:

  - d for # of day
  - M for # of month
  - Y for # of year

Note: I have no idea what i parameter does.

Comment: Thank you. Most helpful! I see there are variables in the URL for p=365d (days?) and i=86400 (not sure what that is). I changed the d value to 7 and a week history showed. d=30 and a month showed. I was trying to get it to display 2 years or more, but had no luck there. Any ideas on that? Again, thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer. I have no idea what i does but you could set it for d, M and Y. For 2 years you could set it for 2Y

Comment: @momo 86400 is the number of seconds in a day, but I'm not sure how the API call uses it.

Comment: Thank you. Implemented at [http://www.cashexchangerates.com/](cashexchangerates.com).

Comment: @max Excellent, good to hear :) If your question is answered, don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the check mark on the left side of the answer. That's how SO Community knows that your question is answered and how all of us contribute and give back to the SO Community. The higher your accept percentage, the likely also people will respond to your next question since that tells them you don't ask question and just run afterwards.